# A differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ is an increasing function between $0$ and $1$. I am looking for the solution of the following differential equation:

$$ \frac{x}{1-x} \frac{1-f(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{ f'(\frac{1+ x}{2})}{f'(\frac{ x}{2}) } $$

One can show that the family of functions $f_a(x)=(2-a) x+(a-1)x^{2}$ solves this differential equation for all $a$ between $0$ and $2$. I would like to show that $f_a$ is the general solution of this equation.

Comment: I dk. But you might get more attention by changing the title.Perhaps "mixed differential & difference equation" .The  presence of x/2 and (1+x)/2 means this is not an "ordinary " O.D.E.